# Equivalent of Spring's "parent" in Castle Windsor

Tags: .net, spring, castle-windsor, spring.net

In Spring Framework (both for java and .net) i can use the following definition of objects:

```
<object id="parentObject" type="Type1" abstract="true">
  <property name="name" value="parent"/>
  <property name="age" value="1"/>
</object>

<object id="childObject" type="Type2" parent="parentObject">
  <property name="name" value="override"/>
  <!-- age will inherit value of 1 from parent -->
</object>
```

Note for **parent** attribute. It is a kind of templating (inheriting of configuration definitions)

Definition of this attribute:
http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.0/reference/html/objects.html#objects-childobjects

What is an equivalent for this in Castle Windsor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windsor has ability to define your components in code which is waaaaay more powerful and it's a recommended way. You can do the "parent" trick by extracting the common code to a helper method.

Config in Windsor is considered legacy, and should not be used except for very limited cases, so in reality you shouldn't need that at all.

Comment: Thank you. Will switch to defining components in the code. But for what cases we still need to use xml config? Do you use xml config for <properties />? If not, where you define constants (in <appConfig />, in code, ...)?

Comment: generally I use appConfig for configuration. You might also bind configuration from AppConfig via DictionaryAdapter. See this post for details: http://codebetter.com/blogs/benhall/archive/2010/07/22/improving-testability-with-the-castle-dictionary-adapter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you say "inherit configuration definition", are you referring to the property values?  You can define a common set of parameters and reference them throughout the config.  See the [Windsor XML reference](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.XML-Registration-Reference.ashx) and the "parameters" node.

Comment: No. About properties it is too obvious. 
I have completely rewrote my question.